# Kinect speech recognition Exception

Tags: c#, exception, kinect, speech-recognition, audio-streaming

How can I use Microsoft.Speech.Recognition with the default audio source. I used `recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()` but an got this Error:

> InvalidOperationExeption: An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Speech.dll

here is my code

```
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartRecognition();
        }

        private SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        private void StartRecognition()
        {
            recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();       //Here is my problem
            recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the least amount of code that demonstrates your problem/error

Comment: "The least amount of code". You have unneeded event handlers and blank lines. Please remove these.

Comment: ok done. I'm sorry I'm new to this ;)

Comment: what is the default audio recording device set to on your pc?

Comment: No worries @fahad. The general idea is to give as much information as possible without providing unnecessary "noise". Cheers.

Comment: the default audio recording device is the microphone near the webcam. I'm trying to use kinect speech engine without the kinect sensor.